# Agrupar por mês - PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Olá, estou aprendedno SQL e travei em ua consulta para o trabalho.
Tenho uma tabela com datas e informações de clientes.
Ex:

```
| data| cod_loja| faturamento |
|:-------- |:------:| -------:|
| 2020-01-01      | 145   | 300   |
```

e preciso agrupar por mês todos esses dados,para ter por mês o faturamento de cada loja.
Ex:

| data | cod_loja | faturamento |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 145 | 800 |

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Você vai ter que usar a função `EXTRACT` para separar por mês,
um exemplo:

> (extract (mounth from CURRENT_DATE)) as mes

Ai pode colocar na parte dos campos e fazer um `Case` para mostrar por extenso, e deve colocar no `Where` para separar como você quer.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá se você precisar retorna o nome do mês por extenso vai ter que utilizar a função datename, lembrando que essa função ira retorna baseado na linguagem do seu bando de dados. Caso não seja necessario voce pode utilizar apenas o month(data) pra retorna o numero do mês exemplo janeiro = 1.

`SELECT
DATENAME(MONTH, MONTH(data)) as data,
cod_Loja,
SUM(vlr_venda) as faturamento
FROM VENDAS WITH (NOLOCK)

GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, MONTH(data)), cod_Loja
ORDER BY data, cod_Loja, faturamento`